# Absolute Path Error in "Cloudways" Hosting with PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPmailer for sending email in PHP. It is working fine on localhost but it gives me an error of absolute path in cloudways hosting server.

**My directory structure.**

-home

- public_html

  - phpmailer
  - sendmail.php

My code for requiring phpmailer is.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/PHPMailer-master/src/phpmailer.php
```

I also tried another approach-

```
require_once '/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/src/phpmailer.php
```

The exact error is-

```
Warning: require_once(/home/152903.cloudwaysapps.com/xxxxxxx/public_html/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/src/phpMailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/152903.cloudwaysapps.com/kjmwdjvxpz/public_html/check2.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/152903.cloudwaysapps.com/kjmwdjvxpz/public_html/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/src/phpMailer.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/152903.cloudwaysapps.com/kjmwdjvxpz/public_html/check2.php on line 5
```

But it does not work. Can someone sort out this problem?

Comment: Please add the exact error message in your question.

Comment: Error Warning: require_once(/home/152903.cloudwaysapps.com/kjmwdjvxpz/public_html/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/src/phpMailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/152903.cloudwaysapps.com/xxxxxxx/public_html/check2.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/152903.cloudwaysapps.com/kjmwdjvxpz/public_html/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/src/phpMailer.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/152903.cloudwaysapps.com/xxxxxx/public_html/check2.php on line 5

Comment: i have edited question with warnings  and fatal error.

Comment: where is the file which you use "require_once" in ?

Comment: it is in public_html

Comment: @TayyabKhanShinwari did you try this ?   require_once  ('/PHPMailer-master/src/phpmailer.php')

Comment: I found the problem its actually PHPMailer.php not phpmailer.php. it is now directing me but it is now giving me error of "page not working when i remove require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php  it is directing me but actually it requires   SMTP

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have a folder named **Phpmailer** but in the require statement I noticed you are using **phpmailer**. Please keep the cases similar otherwise it would not work.

Change **Phpmailer** to **phpmailer** or vice versa depending on the folder name. It works on **windows** this way but would not work on a **linux** system as the names are case-sensitive there.

**Update:**

As above is not the case then please try one of these for require statements-

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/src/phpmailer.php"
```

Or try this-

```
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/src/phpmailer.php"
```

I noticed you are requiring this class in one of your file present in **public_html** folder. So you must tell the code to start searching for the file from **phpmailer** folder instead of searching directly for **PHPMailer-master**. Because **PHPMailer-master** exists in **phpmailer** folder not directly in public_html folder.

Comment: It was my mistake i edited question its same phpmailer in both code and directory structure.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try that and let me know.

Comment: I found the problem its actually PHPMailer.php not phpmailer.php. it is now directing me but it is now giving me error of "page not working when i remove require_once dirname(FILE).'/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php it is directing me but actually it requires SMTP –

Comment: It is throwing some error. Enable the debugger or check the error log to see what it is.

Comment: SMTP could not authenticate  i am using "Gmail".

Comment: It's a common error so please search it on Google and StackOverflow. You will find a solution for sure. If not, then post a question here with details.

Answer (score 0):

On servers, directory structure is such that EXACT paths are needed. As an example, if you go to your server and open yoursite.tld/Phpmailer and the actual directory is PHPMailer, you will get a 404 error because case matters. When requesting a file you need to use that. Another thing you could do is:

```
require_once"./PHPMailer-master/src/phpmailer.php";
```

Or

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__)."PHPMailer-master/src/phpmailer.php
```

Comment: it is actually phpmailer in both code and directory no issue of case sensitivity. check question i edited.

Comment: Here's something I used to use so I wouldn't have to worry about differing paths on my local and remote server
    if (strpos($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'public_html') !== FALSE) {

        $eoaPath = substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],0,strpos($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'public_html'));

    } elseif (strpos($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'www') !== FALSE) {

        $eoaPath = substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],0,strpos($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'www'));

    } else {

        die('Path failure');

    }

Comment: I found the problem its actually PHPMailer.php not phpmailer.php. it is now directing me but it is now giving me error of "page not working when i remove require_once dirname(FILE).'/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php it is directing me but actually it requires SMTP –